# worst case complexity of insertion in a hash table

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

Given an externally chained hash table with load factor 2 and that the hash functions and key comparisons take time, what is the worst-case complexity to insert N items into it?

**My Thoughts** 
We have to insert N items, and the load factor is two, so to insert each item either takes one step or two, so the complexity should be Theta(N)

 I am not sure, though, if this argument is correct

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about the worst-case, you have to think about what happens if the hash table's capacity has to be increased.
Load factor 2 means that the hash table will be rebuilt into one with a higher capacity. The new capacity will be `x * oldcapacity` where i assume x to be about 2.

A bad case would be that N=1 and the full rehashing has to be done. This results in O(N + M) with M being the size of the table. This is the worst case if M >> N.

Let us say the table beins empty. The interesting question is "How many rehashes will we have to do at most?" Assume the Table begins empty with a capacity of 2. Then the first insert will cause the first rehashing. Then the capacity is 4, so that the second insert will cause rehashing. So the elements causing rehashes are [1,2,4,8,16, ...].

This means we have log(N) rehashes of the Table. The hardest question is yet to come. How often is each element rehashed?

- The first element will be rehashed log(N) times.
- The second element will be rehashed log(N-1) times.
- The fourth element will be rehased log(N-2) times.
- The last element will be rehashed 1 time.

The sum of all those rehashed is O(log(n!)) = O(n*log(n))

Comment: I am not too sure with the "The sum of all those rehashed is O(log(n!)) = O(n*log(n))" in the end yet. But i think you will land at O(n*log(n)).